# how to transform japanese english character to normal english character?

Tags: php, string, utf-8, character

I have an japanese english character.
This character is not normal english string.

```
Characters: Ｇａｍｅ
```

How to transform this character to normal english character in **php**?

Comment: What makes those characters Japanese?

Comment: I think he means full-width characters as opposed to half-width characters we use, for example difference between "Ａ" to "A"

Comment: hmm.. I got those characters in japan web site.. I need to convert those characters to normal english characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtract 65248 from the ordinal value of each character. In other words:

```
$str = "Ｇａｍｅ some other text by ヴィックサ";
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    "/[\x{ff01}-\x{ff5e}]/u",
    function($c) {
        // convert UTF-8 sequence to ordinal value
        $code = ((ord($c[0][0])&0xf)<<12)|((ord($c[0][1])&0x3f)<<6)|(ord($c[0][2])&0x3f);
        return chr($code-0xffe0);
    },
    $str);
```

This will replace all of the "Fullwidth" characters with their normal width equivalents.

Comment: How to do the reverse? Please check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22575478/1438393).

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use mb_convert_kana:

```
$string = 'Characters: Ｇａｍｅ';
$newString = mb_convert_kana($string,'a');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a much easier answer but couldnt you make a dictonary object with the special charter as the key and the char you want as the value

then just do a simple find and replace?

Comment: I can't replace those characters.. Include japanese, english, numbers, special chars(★, ☆ and others)...

Comment: I assumed that "Transform" was to look up and replace the unwanted char with the wanted equivalent