# Convert single byte string to double byte string

Tags: php, unicode, encoding

I want the string `Game` to convert `Ｇａｍｅ`. This string is a Japanese double byte string.

Is it possible to achieve this using PHP? If so, how?

Comment: Use [mb_convert_encoding()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) with the appropriate encodings

Comment: @MarkBaker : i would try this mb_convert_encoding() for php but in mysql part... is there any function for this ? because my probable solution would be base on the query directly..

Comment: If you need to do this in MySQL, then use [CONVERT() or CAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-convert.html)

Comment: What encoding? UTF-16?

Comment: @tadman: this is more likely to be UTF8 => SJIS-win in PHP. or utf8 => sjis(Shift-JIS Japanese) in MySQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `Ｇａｍｅ` is not ASCII charset, so you might need to set the page `Content-type` header to see a proper output:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Then you can convert it using this function

```
echo mb_convert_kana('Game', "R", 'UTF-8')
```

**EDIT:**

For MySQL I couldn't find a converter to do the same. However, you can still convert it manually on the Hex level, for example, you can get the word `Ｇａｍｅ` like this

```
SELECT CHAR(0xefbca7, 0xefbd81, 0xefbd8d, 0xefbd85) as `Full Width`;
```

So, we can just write a mapping function in MySQL that replaces the characters using this [table](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=65280&number=256)

Comment: @KraneBird: thanks for your answer in php part...  but how about in mysql part, is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, can't say for sure whether I got your question right, but the following console one-liner:

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(mb_convert_encoding("Game", "UCS-2"));'
```

gives me the following:

```
string(8) "\000G\000a\000m\000e"
```

Is this what you want? As Mark Baker already said, it's just the case of `mb_convert_encoding` for you.

Comment: How would you determine which encoding to use? Using mb_detect_encoding perhaps?

Comment: Man, but *you* are going to convert to the multibyte encoding! I assume that you have control over the input string, and you know to what encoding you want to convert! Use Shift-JIS, for example, or EUC. I have used UCS-2 because it's guaranteed to be exactly two-byte Unicode encoding, as you have specified.

Comment: This doesn't still convert  `Game` => `Ｇａｍｅ`.

Answer (score -1):

you can try for this function [mb_convert_kana](https://www.php.net/mb_convert_kana)

Comment: this is in contrast of what i've wanted to be converted. i want this kind of conversion 'Game' => 'Ｇａｍｅ'